# Why does Safari send the wrong cookie value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, asynchronous, cross-browser

I have code that regularly increments a counter in a cookie value to be sent by AJAX. This works in Chrome/FF/IE, but in Safari, the cookie value that I receive on the server is approximately the JS value + 10.

```
/* Example uses jQuery */
var counter = 0;
function handleInteraction(){
    counter++;
    createCookie("COUNTER", counter, 10);   
}

$('body').on('mousemove', function () {
    handleInteraction();
});

$('body').on('click', function () {
    console.log(counter);
    $.get("http://bryan.co.il/del.php");
    handleInteraction();
});
```

Why is this?

Please provide documentation from Safari if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find related documentation.

Safari seem to have changed the implementation of XHR requests - although this does appear to be allowed by the http specification.

Most browsers, when they send AJAX, they read the cookie value synchronously, and then send the request asynchronously.

Safari however, even reads the cookie value asynchronously (ie. whenever it wants).

Here is some code to demonstrate using createCookie from quirksmode.org:

```
createCookie("TEST_COOKIE", "Before", 10);
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", location.href);
x.send();
createCookie("TEST_COOKIE", "After", 10);
```

In Chrome (etc), the server will receive the "before" cookie. In Safari (tested on Windows, Mac & iPad), the server will receive after!